# Adverb of place vs prepositions

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, adverb-position, prepositional-objects, intensifying-adverbs

- Keep the book **right** on the table.
- Keep the food **down** on the floor.

Are the words *right* and *down*  working as adverbs  or prepositions here?

If they're adverbs,  what do they modify?

If they're prepositions,  what are their objects?

Comment: They're being used as prepositions, but the prepositional phrases in which they appear are adverbial.  Prepositional phrases are modifiers.  They can be either adverbial or adjectival.  In these scenarios, they are adverbial, which might be what is leading to your confusion.  http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-181-Prepositional-Phrases.htm

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Are you saying *right* is a preposition? A book can't be right the table, can it? I'm also uncertain whether food that's fine when it's down the hall can also be equally fine when it's down the floor. Feels down right strange if you ask me. Does that mean strange is a noun then?

Comment: @tchrist: It would be *downright* strange to talk about having ***food down the floor*** (I'd need another preposition; *down **on** the floor*). But I've no problem with saying I wouldn't fancy eating the ***food down your shirt*** (in which context I'm picturing you as a particularly messy spaghetti eater, obviously! :)